# SQL Pivot table for monthly aggregate amount

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

I've not much experience in sql.In my little java program using ucanaccess library I was able to perform some simple queries after creating a simple table (named ReportSales). The table is:

```
ID  DATE            PRODUCT     SALES       FEES
1   2014-10-02      productA    10.000      100
2   2014-09-02      productC    12.000      240
3   2014-09-02      productA    8.000        80
4   2014-11-02      productB    7.000       105
5   2014-08-02      productB    6.000        90
..  ..........      ........    ......      ....
..  ..........      ........    ......      ....
```

The last task is to create a pivot table in which I would insert the monthly sales per product. Something like:

```
PRODUCT     AUG         SEP         OCT      NOV
productA    0         8.000      10.000        0
productB    6000          0           0     7000
productC    0        12.000           0        0
```

And another pivot for monthly fees

My (wrong) attempt is:

```
SELECT [8] as AUG, [9] as SEP, [10] as OCT, [11] as NOV
FROM
(SELECT SALES,MONTH(DATE) 
    FROM ReportSales) AS tmp
PIVOT
(
SUM(SALES)
FOR MONTH(DATE) IN ([8], [9], [10], [11])
) AS PivotTable
```

Does anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you include `PRODUCT` in your subquery, you should get the result you want.

Comment: Tried but doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  That's not a very helpful message.

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be first lines, i've got exception: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: AUG

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's an access database, accdb file v.2007

Comment: The syntax you are using is for SQL Server, you need to use MS Access Pivot syntax. I think that'd be part of the problem.

Comment: I didn't know that. For simple queries was the same and that was the trick... Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCanAccess supports Pivot queries, only if they are built in Access, so you have firstly to create a crosstab query using the Access IDE.
Or you may  simply create a new query in Access entering directly the following SQL:

```
TRANSFORM sum(ReportSales.sales) AS SalesCount
SELECT ReportSales.product
FROM ReportSales
GROUP BY ReportSales.product
PIVOT Format([date],"mmm");
```

Then assuming that you saved the query as query1, you have just to execute, with UCanAccess:

```
Select * from query1;
```